# jquery $(this) works once inside same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#test img:first').ready(function() {      
    var w = $(this).width();
    console.log(w);     

    $('#test img:first').attr('width', 200);
    //$(this).attr('width', 200);
});
```

width of the element is correct
so as setting width via selector
but

```
$(this).attr('width', 200);
```

doesn't work, what am I missing?

Comment: Why are you not using $(this) again?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: I believe you should be using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: @ChristianStewart That's exactly the OP's question: why `$(this)` doesn't work?

Comment: What is the expected behavior here? Do you want the image to re-size and see the result visually?

Comment: Well he has it commented out...

Comment: @mat- perhaps if it was inline...

Comment: Why are you using .ready???

Comment: I just updated my answer - the problem is that `this` isn't the `<img>` element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*edit* — old answer left below

Inside that "ready" handler, `this` is not the `<img>` element. It's the `document` object.

I don't know exactly why, but that's why `this` just doesn't work.

Wait actually I do know why: it's because the "ready" event only applies to the document.  The "load" event would be more relevant, but you won't necessarily get a "load" event either.

---

CSS properties are not element properties:

```
$(this).css('width', '200px');
```

Now, `<img>` elements *do* have a width property.  If you're trying this in a not-so-new Internet Explorer, it might require:

```
$(this).prop('width', 200);
```

Comment: [`<img>` has a width attribute](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/img#HTML_Attributes)

Comment: tried this already, the point is it works like $('#test img:first').css('width', '200px'), but doesn't work with $(this)

Comment: @ExplosionPills yes I was adding that :-)

Comment: He should not use ready on an element. That's the problem here.

Comment: @Pointy but why $(this).width() returns different values, depending on image?

Comment: @Nenad yes precisely.  I thought that looked kind-of funny but I was slow to realize the issue :-)

Comment: @Herokiller because the size of the image affects the size of the document. Add a `console.log(this)` to the function and you'll see.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `$(this).width(200);` instead.

Comment: @Herokiller See Pointy's answer. Has to do with the `.ready()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test img:first').ready(function() {
    var t = $(this),
        w = t.width();
    t.css({width:200+"px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this (proper document.ready function):

```
$(function() {  
    $img = $('#test img:first');
    var w = $img.width();
    console.log(w);

    $img.attr('width', 200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are good, but the original problem I think was that in this part...

```
$(this).attr('width', 200);
```

the value of 200 should have been enclosed in single quotes. Width is a valid attribute on an image tag, but all attributes are strings even if they look numeric.